# how to create password to folder Or secure folder using c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, dotnetzip, file-security

I am working on a windows form application using c#. There are some important files near my project that I do not want anyone to have access them but my application needs files.
The first solution was using DotNetZip library with password.
But when the application want to use these files the zip file must unzipped and all files copy in hard disk.
Is there a solution without direct access to the files to use them?
Or is there a solution that can be secured folders?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider encrypting the passwords and not worry about people accessing it. If this does not work then you could also consider using a database to store your passwords.